# width of grid view boundfield

Tags: asp.net, gridview, boundfield

I can not set the width of bound field. Is there any problem in the following markup.

```
 <asp:BoundField DataField="UserName" HeaderText="User Name"
                   meta:resourcekey="BoundFieldUNCUserNameResource1">
        <HeaderStyle Width="50%" />
 </asp:BoundField>
```

[image]

Please refer to the image. I set width using the following. The yellow colored numbers are corresponding width. The marked user name is always Wrapped even I set a width to a large value (say 50%) and set Wrap="false".

```
<HeaderStyle Width="20%" Wrap="true" />
<ItemStyle Width="20%" Wrap="true" />
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Try This:

`ItemStyle-Width="50%" ItemStyle-Wrap="false"` in the BoundField tag

Comment: ItemStyle-Width="120px" is not effective when Wrap="false". Why?

Comment: This seems to have no effect on asp:GridView.

Answer (score 9):

For BoundField:

```
 <asp:BoundField DataField="UserName" HeaderText="User Name" ItemStyle-Width="50px" />
```

Answer (score 2):

It's amazing that even now, in 2016, the `ItemStyle-Width` and `HeaderStyle-Width` attributes usually get ignored in the ASP.Net `GridView` control.

Sometimes, they just seem to create no markup whatsoever.

My solution was to give up trying to set this attributes, and I resorted to using plain old CSS instead:

```
.AspNet-GridView table tbody tr td:nth-child(1)
{
    /*  Set the width of the 1st GridView column */
    width: 200px;
}
.AspNet-GridView table tbody tr td:nth-child(2)
{
    /*  Set the width of the 2nd GridView column */
    width: 300px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing this problem today. What i got is you must define ur width in css class & called that css class in boundfeild.
e.g.

```
HeaderStyle-CssClass="width350"
```

Answer (score 0):

To change column width gridview boundfield just add this inside boundfield

```
ItemStyle-Width="200"  ItemStyle-Wrap="False"
```

it worked for me, try this

Answer (score 0):

After trying several solutions with no luck, I was able to add a css class to the item. Seems like both HeaderStyle-CssClass and ItemStyle-CssClass attributes needed to be set:

```
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" HeaderStyle-CssClass="Name" ItemStyle-CssClass="Name" />
```